# How to define/declare the type of a Closure delegate?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to define a builder pattern to construct the command-line arguments of a Cucumber action for our Jenkins CI/CD pipeline. In it, I'm trying to write the data class with a Closure method as well in the event someone prefers that syntax (trying to be flexible). So I defined this (abridged for brevity):

```
class CucumberArgs {
    private Boolean _help
    
    CucumberArgs() {}

    Boolean getHelp() {
        return this._help;
    }

    CucumberArgs help(Boolean value) {
        this._help = value;
        return this;
    }
    
    static CucumberArgs with(Closure<CucumberArgs> builder) {
        builder.delegate = new CucumberArgs();
        builder.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY;
        return builder.call();
    }

    @Override
    String toString() {
        if(this._help) {
            return 'cucumber-js --help'
        }
    }
}

def args = CucumberArgs.with {
    help(true);
}

println args
// 'cucumber-js --help'
```

As I've said, there's a lot more to the code, but it's a succinct example of what I'm doing. In IntelliJ, I get the message that `No candidates found for method call help.` I'm sure the answer has been given before, but I can't seem to pick the right search query. Official documentation is preferred, but I'd be fine with a working code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I threw this into Intellij in a Groovy Console and ran it.  I did make a little clean up, but it was mostly cosmetic.  I couldn't get it to fail so I think mostly what you had was fine.  You weren't returning a string in all cases in `toString()`, and I added the `@DelegatesTo` so Intellij would know what your delegate would be.  That recognizes the help method, but even without that it worked.  That was the most substantive change.

```
class CucumberArgs {
    private Boolean _help

    CucumberArgs() {}

    Boolean getHelp() {
        return this._help
    }

    CucumberArgs help(Boolean value) {
        this._help = value
        return this
    }

    static CucumberArgs with(@DelegatesTo(CucumberArgs) Closure<CucumberArgs> builder) {
        builder.delegate = new CucumberArgs()
        builder.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
        return builder.call()
    }

    @Override
    String toString() {
        if(this._help) {
            return 'cucumber-js --help'
        } else {
            return ''
        }
    }
}

def args = CucumberArgs.with {
    help(true)
}

println args
// 'cucumber-js --help'
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. Also, good call on the `toString` method. I had it fully-implemented in my code, but didn't manage the else case in the sample.